# Creating a Dice Roller in Java with an Array List. (Not and Array)

Tags: java, indexing, printing, output, dice

I am currently lost as to what I should to do make this work. The assignment has already been turned in, but I am trying to be a good student and figure out why it wouldn't work. Here is the problem I was given:

A run is a sequence of adjacent repeated values. Write a Java class with one main method that generates a
sequence of 20 random die tosses in an `ArrayList` and that prints the die values, marking the runs by including
them in parentheses, like this:

```
1 2 (5 5) 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5) 6 3 1
```

Pseudocode:
Hint: Use the following pseudocode:
Set a boolean variable inRun to false.
For each valid index i in the ArrayList
 If inRun
 If `values[i]` is different from the preceding value
 Print ).
 inRun = false.
 If not inRun
 If values[i] is the same as the following value
 Print (.
 inRun = true.
 Print values[i].
If inRun, print ).

I know there are a bunch of questions like this, but I swear I have seen them all. I could not find one similar enough that used an ArrayList versus an Array.

Here is my code:

```
package run;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRoller {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean inRun = false;
    int roll;

    ArrayList randomNumList = new ArrayList();
    Random randNum = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        roll = randNum.nextInt(6);
        randomNumList.add(roll);
    }

    //Gets the size of the ArrayList.
    int sizeOfArray = randomNumList.size();

    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        if (inRun == true)
        {
            if (randomNumList.indexOf(i) == randomNumList.lastIndexOf(i)) //PROBLEM AREA//
            {
                System.out.print(")");
            }
            inRun = false;
        }

        if (inRun == false)
        {
            if(randomNumList.indexOf(i) == randomNumList.indexOf(i))//PROBLEM AREA//
            {
                System.out.print("(");
                inRun = true;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(randomNumList);
}
```

I can not for the life of me and the internet figure out why I could not get the correct output. I first tried to do `if(randomNumList[] == randomNumList[i-1]` and `if(randomNumList[i] == randomNumList[i+1](i))`. This was all I could find online, but gave me the error that it would not work with an `ArrayList` it needed an `Array`. So the way it is in the code if how I got it up till now. Output looks something like this:

```
(((((()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()([4, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 0, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5]
```

Please help!!

Comment: the classic already been turned in trick.  How do we know this? If you already turned it in can't you just ask your professor?

Comment: This site is for help isn't it? It is turned in by the way, but I am trying to make an effort to better understand the material. And I can't ask the professor because it it 1 in the morning. I need help not criticism. Rson1234

Comment: Sorry that my comment bothered you, but I get bothered by so many future programmers come in with assignments without figuring it out for themselves using all other resources first.  You don't have to figure it out at 1am either.  Hope someone can help you but I will only provide hints.  Hopefully that is all you end up getting.  You are the future.  So become it please.  This is bigger than an assignment.  Think deep.  You will find it

Comment: Start with this.  You said you found something similar that used an array rather than an arraylist.  So what's the difference?  Figure out what an arraylist actually is.  See if you can convert something that is done with the array to the way you need it.  Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from the basics. First of all you should output each element of the list one by one inside the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
    System.out.print(randomNumList.get(i) + 1);
}
```

This will print each dice roll. The `+1` is because dices has numbers from 1 to 6, not from 0 to 5.
Now let's improve our code by considering the parenthesis cases:

1. Print a `(` **before** the dice roll print if a certain condition is verified
2. Print a `)` **after** the dice roll print if another certain condition is verified

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
    // Print '(' if ...
    System.out.print(randomNumList.get(i) + 1);
    // Print ')' if ...
}
```

What you need to test is the "next element", the `i+1` one. If it is the same as the current one and you are not in a run, you should print `(` before anything else. Alternatively, if you actually are in a run BUT the next one breaks it, you should print a `)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
    boolean isNextTheSame = (i+1 < sizeOfArray) && randomNumList.get(i+1) == randomNumList.get(i);
    if (!inRun && isNextTheSame) {
        System.out.print("(");
        inRun = true;
    }
    System.out.print(randomNumList.get(i) + 1);
    if (inRun && !isNextTheSame) {
        System.out.print(")");
        inRun = false;
    }
}
```

In your pseudocode it tests the previous element in order to verify the second condition, and not the next one. But the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

First, your display is totally buggy because you're doing a first loop displaying only the parenthesis then a sysout of the array list.

Then, your algorithm is not good
An ArrayList can be accessed like an array (just use .get(index)), this is not a problem 
You should study in details the functions of ArrayList, I think you have not understand what lastIndexOf and indexOf are doing

I sugest you to doing this : by traducting in Java the hint given
Please note : if object in ArrayList are Integer, you have to use equals instead of ==

```
boolean inRun = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
            // If inRun If values[i] is different from the preceding value Print
            // ).
            if (inRun && randomNumList.get(i) != randomNumList.get(i - 1)) {
                System.out.print(") ");
                inRun = false;
            } else
            // If not inRun If values[i] is the same as the following value
            // Print (
            if (!inRun && i < sizeOfArray - 1 && randomNumList.get(i) == randomNumList.get(i + 1))
            {
                System.out.print("( ");
                inRun = true;
            }

            System.out.print(randomNumList.get(i) + " ");
        }

        if (inRun) {
            System.out.print(") ");
        }
```